# SQL query with 5 tables using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very complex SQL server database that I have attempted to simplify here.  I have 5 tables that I would like to pull information from.  I want all records from Table_A.  The other tables may or may not have records in them.  when they do I want that information added to my final table.  I can't get query to return correct values.  I've tried different joins, etc but keep getting the same values.

**Table_A**:

```
LotID     MaterialNumber        RejectReason   
1234      987                   16
2345      876   
3456      987
4567      876
5678      987
6789      987                   15
7890      987           
8901      987
```

**Table_B**:

```
LotID     Color  
1234      0.25
5678      0.28
6789      0.27
8901      0.3
```

**Table_C**:

```
LotID     Gloss  
1234      1.25
2345      1.28
6789      1.27
8901      1.30
```

**Table_D**:

```
LotID   Thickness  
2345    2.25
5678    2.28
6789    2.27
7890    2.3
```

**Table_E**:

```
NR      Description
12      Tear
13      Run
14      Drip
15      Wet
16      Dry
```

**Table_F**:

```
Material_Number Part_Descrip

987         Front
876         Rear
```

Query

```
Select
    Table_A.LotID, Table_A.MaterialNumber,
    Table_B.Color,
    Table_C.Gloss,
    Table_D.Thickness
    Table_E.Description,
    Table_F.Part_Descrip,
FROM 
    Table_A A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_B B ON A.LotID = B.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_C C ON A.LotID = C.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_D D ON A.LotID = D.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_E E ON A.RejectReason = E.NR
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_F F ON A.MaterialNumber = F.Material_Number
ORDER BY 
    A.LotID
```

Returning:

```
LotID    Material Number    Color   Gloss   Thickness   Reject  Part Description
6789     987                0.27    1.28    2.27        Wet     Front
```

Want it to return:

```
LotID   Material Number Color   Gloss   Thickness   Reject  Part Description
1234    987             0.25    1.25    Null        Dry     Front
2345    876             Null    1.28    2.25        Null    Rear
3456    987             Null    Null    Null        Null    Front
4567    876             Null    Null    Null        Null    Rear
5678    987             0.28    1.28    2.28        Null    Front
6789    987             0.27    1.28    2.27        Wet     Front
7890    987             Null    Null    2.3         Null    Front
8901    987             0.3     1.3     Null        Null    Front
```

ORIGINAL Query

```
SELECT
Z_LINE5_QU.CollectTime,
Z_LINE5_QU.LotID, 
Z_LINE5_QU.MOULD_ID, 
Z_LINE5_QU.CAV,
Z_LINE5_QU.MOULD_CAV,
Z_LINE5_QU.OK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.NOK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.OKAFTERREWORK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.NOKAFTERREWORK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.SENDTOREWORK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.SPOTCH_OK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.SPOTCH_NOK, 
Z_LINE5_QU.MOULD_CY, 
Z_LINE5_QU.LINE, 
Z_LINE5_QU.LINE_ID, 
Z_LINE5_QU.REASON_NR1, 
Z_CODE_QU_REASON.DESCR, 
Z_CODE_PART.PART_DESCR,
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_GLOSS.GLOSS_MP1, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_GLOSS.GLOSS_MP2, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z1, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z2, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z3, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z4, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z5, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z6, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z7, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z8, 
Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.THICK_Z9

FROM RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_LINE5_QU Z_LINE5_QU

        LEFT OUTER JOIN RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_COLOR
              ON Z_LINE5_QU.LOTID = Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_COLOR.LOTID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK
              ON Z_LINE5_QU.LOTID=Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_THICK.LOTID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_GLOSS
              ON Z_LINE5_QU.LOTID=Z_LINE5_SPOTCH_GLOSS.LOTID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_CODE_QU_REASON
              ON Z_LINE5_QU.REASON_NR1=Z_CODE_QU_REASON.NR

        LEFT OUTER JOIN RTUSPRAY.DBO.Z_CODE_PART
              ON Z_LINE5_QU.CODE_SAP = Z_CODE_PART.CODE_SAP_PRESER

ORDER BY Z_LINE5_QU.LotID
```

Comment: A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the correct one you want to be doing.  That query looks correct as well.  Any chance you can paste your original query?

Comment: You may want give an executable script to check any issue; It is difficult to expect SO members to write their own CREATE, INSERT scripts for you!! By the way, looking at your query, it does look like correct;

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your query. It should be giving you your desired results.

Comment: can you post just the FROM clause of your actual query?  What you may want to do is comment out some of your joins to see which ones aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: @beth, the Join's are not restricting any records since they are LEFT OUTER JOINS and Table_A is the Leftmost table. Given the sample data and the SQL listed, all records should come back, which leads me to believe that OP's actual query is different then the example here (Especially since this SQL wouldn't even run since it has misplaced commas in the SELECT clause).

Comment: @jnevill, actually, I wouldn't be surprised if he has some references to the outer tables in his WHERE clause, so it's ignoring the OUTER JOIN entirely.

Comment: Totally agree. I suspect there is either an INNER JOIN not being listed, an omiited WHERE clause, or Table_A is the smaller of the tables. We may never know...

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up recreating it all in my database and it worked fine. The only difference is I used the table aliases in the select list versus the actual table names like shown in the original question:

```
 Select
A.LotID,
A.MaterialNumber,
B.Color,
C.Gloss,
D.Thickness,
E.Description,
F.Part_Descrip
FROM 
    dbo.Table_A as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_B as B ON A.LotID = B.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_C as C ON A.LotID = C.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_D as D ON A.LotID = D.LotID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_E as E ON A.RejectReason = E.NR
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table_F as F ON A.MaterialNumber = F.Material_Number
ORDER BY 
    A.LotID
```

Here are my results:

```
    LotID   MaterialNumber  Color   Gloss   Thickness   Description Part_Descrip
    1234    987             0.000   1.25    NULL        Dry         Front
    2345    876             NULL    1.28    2.25        NULL        Rear
    3456    987             NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        Front
    4567    876             NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        Rear
    5678    987             0.280   NULL    2.28        NULL        Front
    6789    987             0.270   1.27    2.27        Wet         Front
    7890    987             NULL    NULL    2.3         NULL        Front
    8901    987             0.300   1.3     NULL        NULL        Front
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems as though you have joined every table by LotID. Seeing as though the only LotID they share is 6789, the result reflects this. I think what you want to do is, since they all share the same unique identifier, is actually create just one table from A through D with more than two columns per table. Assuming table E column NR corresponds to the third column of Table A, that is where you want one join. The only other join should be Table A with Table F column `MaterialNumber`. This way you only need two joins. Otherwise I believe you would actually need a combination (remember permutations?) of the five joins that you have in your question.

Comment: This would be true if OP was using INNER JOINs, but they are using LEFT OUTER JOIN which will select all records from Table_A and only those from downstream tables that match.